# The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)

Tags: regex, swift, cocoa

I am a little new to using regex.
I am getting the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)

when trying to build the following regular expression with NSRegularExpression in Swift:

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{7-15}$", options: .CaseInsensitive)
```

I am trying to validate the user input string to contain at least one upper case letter and at least one lower case letter while restricting the length of the string to between 7 and 15 characters. Thanks

Comment: Two things should be changed, I think: 1) fix the limiting quantifier from `{7-15}` to `{7,15}`, 2) Remove the `.CaseInsensitive` flag, replace with `[]`. (if the `[]` is not accepted, try `nil` instead).

Comment: Thanks, I see your point, I replaced the .CaseInsensitive flag with [ ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern isn't totally correct. The length range syntax uses a comma:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{7,15}$"
```

Comment: happens:) would be nice if you approved the answer, unless you wanna get rid of the question all together

Comment: If you use this with `options: .CaseInsensitive`, strings like `abcdefgh` will also pass.

Answer (score 1):

In order to valide the user input, use this regex :

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.{7})(?!.{16}).+$

^               // start of the string
(?=.*[a-z])     // assert that at least one lowercase exists
(?=.*[A-Z])     // assert that at least one uppercase exists
(?=.{7})        // assert that at least 7 characters exists
(?!.{16})       // assert that the string cannot exceed 15 characters (negative lookahead)
.+              // get the entire string
$               // end of the string
```

You can check [the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/rP0pH8/1).

Comment: That link is awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @Maria1985 I'm glad it could help. If it useful to you, don't forget to vote up. It'd be highly appreciated. Have a nice day ;)